# Removing ballpoint ink signature from inside flap of hardback book

Tags: books, stain

I have a 40 year old collectible hardback book in which a signature was made on the inside flap using blue ballpoint ink.  I've done some research and come away with a couple of options, but hoping someone here might have done some restoration work:

1. Mechanical means

   - Sand Eraser such as Tombow Mono
   - Razor blade
2. Chemical means

   - Acetone on q-tip
   - Rubbing alcohol (w/ qtip)
   - Lemon juice (w/ qtip)
   - Lamy Ink Eraser

I'd like to do as good a job as possible as the book has a bit of value if I can remove my, and my brother's, old signatures (see picture).

**Has anyone tried any of the methods above (or something else entirely)?

Is there a better stack exchange site for this style of question?**

Given that this is a hardbound book, I can do a bit of scraping without wearing through the paper *too* much but not sure if it will leave a surface that is completely mismatched from the surrounding paper either by color or texture.

[image: ink signature, inside flap]

Comment: The book has dog-eared corners, so it's not in very good condition. You could risk damaging it and reducing its value further; or entrust it to a professional book restorer; or sell it "as is". Have you had a valuation?

Comment: None of these kinds of books being sold are in great condition.  Based on what I see on eBay it's probably somewhere between $75 - $350, and probably on the lower end.

Answer (score 0):

put a small amount of hand-sanitizer on the back of your hand and get a tissue  or a paper towel and poke the corner in the hand sanitizer and put it on the ink and it should get it off

Answer (score 0):

Ballpoint ink:

Cyclohexane (camp stove fuel)
Isoproply alcohol (rubbing alcohol)

Test ball point pen ink on some other piece of paper.  If it works try cautiously on part of the problem.